# how do I draw a dot without filling it with matplotlib.pyplot.plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Both plt.scatter and plt.plot can draw dots

this code draws a dot without filling it

```
plt.scatter(1, 1, s=80, facecolors='none', edgecolors='r')
```

[image]

while `plt.plot` doesn't seem to support `facecolors` property

```
plt.plot(1,1,'ro')
```

[image]

how do I draw a dot without filling it with plt.plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For regular plots, you can use `markerfacecolor`:

```py
plt.plot(1, 1, 'ro', markerfacecolor='none')
```

[image: plt.plot with markerfacecolor='none']